# Blinking text in status bar

Tags: c#, wpf, timer, statusbar

I am trying to implement a warning system when a user tries to do an illegal action in my form. The idea is to call `StatusBarFade` method, give it the parameter it should write, than have that method display the text, make it blink by changing it's color for a second and a half, and then stay another second and a half, after which the text will disappear.

The blinking works every other time, while the text disappears normally.

Please note that I know this code is quite messy and there is surely a better way to do it, but since I don't exactly know how delegates work I don't know how to utilize them properly. Hopefully someone will be able to explain what I'm doing wrong. Anyway, after some testing I realized that it's best to have two timers. The problem is that this code works every other time.

```
    private Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    private Timer timerColor = new System.Timers.Timer();
    private void StatusBarFade(string ispis)
    {
        statusBar1AS2.Content = ispis;
        int i = 0;
        timerColor.Interval = 100;
        timerColor.AutoReset = true;
        timerColor.Elapsed += delegate(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    ++i;
                    if (statusBar1AS2.Foreground == Brushes.Black)
                        statusBar1AS2.Foreground = Brushes.Gold;
                    else
                        statusBar1AS2.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
                    if (i > 15)
                    {
                        statusBar1AS2.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
                        i = 0;
                        timerColor.Stop();
                    }
                }));
        };
        timerColor.Start();

        timer.Interval = 3000;
        timer.Elapsed += delegate(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { statusBar1AS2.Content = ""; }));
        };
        timer.Start();
    }
```

As far as I understand delegates, I shouldn't be adding the same delegate to the timer.Elapsed event every time the text is changed, but rather only once, in the constructor, for example. The problem is that I don't know how to use the counter `i` in the way that I did in the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply use the following animation:

```
var animation = new ColorAnimation
{
    From = Colors.Black,
    To = Colors.Gold,
    AutoReverse = true,
    Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1),
    RepeatBehavior = new RepeatBehavior(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5))
};

animation.Completed += (o, e) => statusBar.Content = string.Empty;

statusBar.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush();
statusBar.Foreground.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, animation);
```

UPDATE: In order to delay the removal of the message, you may of course use a timer. You could perhaps write your StatusBarFade method like shown below, with a [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615945.aspx):

```
private void StatusBarFade(string message)
{
    statusBar.Content = message;

    var animation = new ColorAnimation
    {
        From = Colors.Gold,
        To = Colors.Black,
        AutoReverse = true,
        Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1),
        RepeatBehavior = new RepeatBehavior(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5)),
    };

    statusBar.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush();
    statusBar.Foreground.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, animation);

    var timer = new DispatcherTimer
    {
        Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4.5)
    };

    timer.Tick +=
        (o, e) =>
        {
            timer.Stop();
            statusBar.Content = string.Empty;
        };

    timer.Start();
}
```

Comment: So I would create the animation in the constructor, then change the statusBar.Foreground property in the StatusBarFade method?

As far as I can see, this will blink the text for a second and a half, and then remove the text, will it not? I need the text to blink for 1.5 seconds, and then stay for another X (probably 3) seconds before being removed. Could I create a composite animation, or should I simply use this animation in combination with the timer used to remove the text in the above code?

Answer (score 0):

try with storyboard.

```
<Storyboard x:Key="TestBlinkStoryboard" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Black"/>
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="#FFE91414">
                <EasingColorKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <BounceEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                </EasingColorKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingColorKeyFrame>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Clemens's answer is what your looking for. I just wanted to find out the reason for this behavior.

The issue your experiencing is due to the fact of attaching delegate's without removing them once an iteration of the timer is completed.

Hence why you see this behavior on every even occurrence since at those times even number of delegates are attached to the timer's elapsed event and thus it pretty much increases in increments of 2,4,6,... Thus ends up going from Black -> Black and we never see the switch to Gold. the overall time of the animation also drops down incrementally in the same fashion. That was the issue.

Fix for that would be(please **do not** use this. Just see it as a case. Use @Clemens approach or have the Storyboard in xaml directly)

```
private int i = 0;

private void StatusBarFade(string ispis) {
  i = 0;
  statusBar1AS2.Content = ispis;
  timerColor.Interval = 100;
  timerColor.AutoReset = true;
  timerColor.Elapsed += TimerColorOnElapsed;
  timerColor.Start();
}

private void TimerColorOnElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs elapsedEventArgs) {
  Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
    (new Action(
      () => {
        ++i;
        statusBar1AS2.Foreground = i % 2 == 0 || i > 15 ? Brushes.Black : Brushes.Gold;
        if (i < 30)
          return;
        timerColor.Stop();
        timerColor.Elapsed -= TimerColorOnElapsed;
        statusBar1AS2.Content = string.Empty;
      })));
}
```